# Can we make arguments that Pluto should be considered a planet off-topic?

Tags: discussion

It has been over 14 years since the IAU passed its definition of what constitutes a planet, and we still get arguments (mostly rants) against that decision. For example, [Where to submit, or ask to submit, a proposal for a redefinition of a planet to the IAU?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40925) The question in question was closed (including by me, as a doxing request).

These people are not asking for a rationale for the definition. These people appear to approach the issue from a point of irrationality and intransigence. Moreover, whether or not one likes the definition, there is nothing we can do about it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we all (aside from the ranters) already agree these are not good questions, hence the closure. If you'd like me to delete it as well, I'm good with doing that.

Comment: @called2voyage Go for the trifecta (negatively downvoted, closed, deleted).

Comment: All right, it's gone.

Comment: Related: [Pile-on down voting...](/q/575)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also added this to the [topic guidelines](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center:

> **My question about Pluto got removed. How is that off topic?**
>
> Was it really a question, or was it a rant about why you think the IAU decision to reclassify Pluto should be reversed? We don't welcome rants-as-questions here period, but we are especially tired of this particular rant. Please stop. If you don't think your question falls in this category, feel free to bring it up on meta.

Comment: You could add Michael for added emphasis: https://i.imgur.com/bNuFnju.gif